# Table is full even with innodb_file_per_table

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-5.6, online-operations

I am trying to create an index to my table using alter query.
My my.cnf file

```
innodb_data_home_dir = /usr/local/mysql5/data
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:60021538816;ibdata2:300M;ibdata3:30000M;ibdata4:10000M;ibdata5:10000M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 3
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 128M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 100
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

Still every time my alter query

```
alter table user add unique index idx_emailHash (emailHash);
```

giving Table 'user' is full?
What am I missing. I am using MySQL 5.6

Some more info

```
[root@db data]# ll | grep user
    -rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql       19551 Jun 10 14:33 user.frm
    -rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 28412215296 Jun 10 22:58 user.ibd

[root@db data]# ll | grep ibd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mysql mysql 60021538816 Jun 10 22:58 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql   314572800 Jun 10 22:20 ibdata2
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 31457280000 Jun 10 22:33 ibdata3
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 10485760000 Jun 10 22:51 ibdata4
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 10485760000 Jun 10 22:51 ibdata5
```

Comment: can you add the complte error message and also see what is in the error log of mysql and syslog

Comment: Which OS are you using? Those file permissions look very, very wrong. MySQL on many Debian-based OSes (such as Ubuntu) will react if file permissions are even slightly outside of expected values.

Comment: This is CentOs but it's a dev server, not a prod/staging one.

Comment: we're missing SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname\G output here.

Answer (score 0):

When InnoDB says a table is full, it has nothing to do with the OS. It has to do with filling an undo logs. InnoDB has 128 undo logs but a single operation can fill just undo until it cannot record any more changes to hold during the indexing operation.

I once had a client that had 106GB free inside 2TB of system table file (ibdat1a, ibdata2). My solution was add another file (ibdata3). The client was not using innodb_file_per_table (See my old post [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412))

You are using innodb_file_per_table. Still, undo logs have limits as to the amount of MVCC info it holds.

I have mentioned this situation over the last 10 years in the DBA StackExchange.

- `Feb 22, 2018` : [The table is full - MariaDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198569/the-table-is-full-mariadb/198602#198602)
- `Jun 16, 2014` : [MySQL Index creation failing on table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68319/mysql-index-creation-failing-on-table-is-full/68326#68326)
- `Mar 31, 2014` : [mysql directory grow to 246G after one query, which failed due to table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62107/mysql-directory-grow-to-246g-after-one-query-which-failed-due-to-table-is-full/62108#62108)
- `May 31, 2013` : [`ERROR 1114 (HY000) the table ... is full` with innodb_file_per_table set to autoextend](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table-set-to-aut/43577#43577)
- `Nov 26, 2011` : [ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 6308 in file & The table user_analysis is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/error-1114-hy000-at-line-6308-in-file-the-table-user-analysis-is-full/8412#8412)

## Possible Workaround #1

Since you are using MySQL 5.6, [trying using Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html).

```
alter table user
    add unique index idx_emailHash (emailHash)
   ,algorithm=inplace
   ,lock=none
;
```

That way, changes will be put into a temp table rather than glutting the Undo Logs.

## Possible Workaround #2

If Workaround #1 does not work, then use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html). I mentioned using it back in September 2019 ([Adding indexes to production MySQL database without downtime?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/247393/adding-indexes-to-production-mysql-database-without-downtime/247395#247395))

You would do something like this

```
pt-online-schema-change user --alter "add unique index idx_emailHash (emailHash)"
```

This will handle all the gory details in a temp table using triggers.